# Why doesn't my ESP-01 start up correctly?

Tags: esp8266

I'm trying to make a radio controlled plane using ESP-01 as the receiver. The communication protocol I'm using is esp-now by espressif. When I plug in the ESP-01 and the motor at the same time, the transmitter returns that the delivery failed. However, when I plug in the esp-01 first, then the motor, it works fine.

Here's my schematic:
[image]
BTW I used an arduino instead of an ESP-01.

Can someone explain why this happens and are there any solutions to it?

Comment: In a general level or specific to your circuit? If the latter, you should post your circuit. The question sounds very familiar - have you asked this before?

Comment: Yes, I asked before and deleted it because it wasn't clear enough. I have also added the schematic as requested.

Comment: That's not an ESP-01, that's an Arduino.

Comment: I just put an arduino there because fritzing doesnt have an esp-01. My bad, I forgot to edit that in.

Comment: Does D2 on you connection resembles GPIO2 pin of ESP-01? Does the Q1 base connected directly to it and emitter to a ground without any resistors?

Comment: Unless you say exactly what you have connected where and how, we can't help you, because we don't know what you have done.

Comment: Lack of decoupling? Vcc sagging under load?

Comment: Try adding a resistor (say 10k) from Q1 base to ground. Without it the motor may run when there is no ERSP and the motor noise may affect the processor. Also, add a reverse polarity diode across the motor mounted physically and electrically near the motor terminals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you schematics D2 pin resembles pin 2 (GPIO2) of the ESP-01, you are pulling it low during the startup through Q1. According to the [ESP8266 docs](https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/boards.html#minimal-hardware-setup-for-bootloading-and-usage) GPIO0 & GPIO2 should be pulled high to boot from on-board SPI Flash (where you store your program).

You can move your motor control pin to GPIO1 (pin 8) or GPIO3 (pin 4) instead.

Also, it's bettor to add a resistor in series with Q1 base to limit base-emitter current as ESP8266 pin can really source only 12 mA of current. Back EMF diode for the motor is also mandatory. In the end it should look similar to [this](https://www.instructables.com/12V-Motor-Control-With-5V-Arduino-and-NPN-Transist/):

[image: Motor Connection Scematic]

R1 will depend on your parameters. But most likely providing you are running your ESP-01 from 3.3V it should be somewhere around 470-1000 ohm, but > 225 ohm to limit current below 12 mA.